# jQuery slideToggle nested list ul li structure

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

```
   $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.current))")
       .find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
       .click(function() {
           $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
       });
```

I have the above code that uses a nested ul li, and expands the levels on click. However I'd like to contract the level on a second click, but the above contracts all the levels and not just the one being click on.

Edit: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FkT62/) for example

Comment: Could you put together a quick jsFiddle?

Comment: @Scott: added jsfiddle example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're intending to do, but I think you can avoid the unwanted sliding by checking to see if the event originated on the handler element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav ul li:not(:has(li.current))").find("ul").hide().end() // Hide all other ULs
    .click(function(e) {
        if (this == e.target) {  // if the handler element is where the event originated
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FkT62/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use toggle() and return false to stop propagation:
[`Use This Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/bouillard/qvgUS/)

Comment: That kinda works... but I suppose my example was incomplete. Some of those li's have links (a tag) and that kills the link.

Comment: Updated jsfiddle to more accurately reflect the links.

Comment: You can test if target is the li (I have updated my jsfiddle)

Comment: That doesn't seem to expand at all.